# Программа работает только во время отладки. При запуске вне отладчика - ошибка времени выполнения

Tags: c, gcc, память

```
#include "txtfile.h"


void strcat_mem(char **dest, char * src)
{
    char * buf;

    if (*dest != NULL)
    {
        buf = (char*)calloc(strlen(*dest) + strlen(src), sizeof(char));
        strcpy(buf, *dest);
        strcat(buf, src);
        free(*dest);
    }
    else
    {
        buf = (char*)calloc(strlen(src), sizeof(char));
        strcat(buf, src);
    }
    *dest = buf;
}

char *fstrread(FILE *f)
{
    char *line = NULL;
    char *buf = calloc(BUF_LEN, sizeof(char));

    while (fgets(buf, BUF_LEN, f) != NULL)
        if (buf[strlen(buf) - 1] == '\n')
        {
            strcat_mem(&line, buf);
            break;
        }
        else
            strcat_mem(&line, buf);

    free(buf);
    strtok(line, "\n");
    return line;
}
```

Код основной программы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "errcode.h"
#include "txtfile.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    FILE *f =fopen("in.txt", "rt");

    printf("%s\n", fstrread(f));

    fclose(f);
    return ERR_OK;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первая ошибка у вас здесь:

```
FILE *f =fopen("in.txt", "rt");
```

Вы не проверяете ошибку при открытии файла.

Вторая - здесь:

```
buf = (char*)calloc(strlen(*dest) + strlen(src), sizeof(char));
/* ... */
buf = (char*)calloc(strlen(src), sizeof(char));
```

Памяти вы обоих случаях выделяется на 1 байт меньше чем нужно (забыли про завершающий 0 в C-строках). Поведение программы в этом случае не определено. В одних ситуациях факт записи за пределы выделенного буфера может ни на чём не сказаться, а в других - отформатировать винчестер...

И третья недоработка здесь:

```
printf("%s\n", fstrread(f));
```

Указатель на память, которая выделена в `fstrread()`, нигде не сохраняется и память не освобождается. В данном случае это не страшно (память всё равно освободится при завершении программы), но вообще так делать - плохая привычка.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, например...

```
buf = (char*)calloc(strlen(src), sizeof(char));
strcat(buf, src);
```

А место для нулевого символа кто выделять будет?... Выделяете вы `strlen(src)` байт, а копируете-то `strlen(src)+1`...